# How do i run function in google cloud faster by using parallel execution?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, google-cloud-firestore

I have a web scraping code that scrapes image from 30 web pages it takes nearly 2 minutes , but if i scrape only one page , it takes approx 4 seconds , so if all run in parallel i would get result in 4 seconds only

Comment: Most of the wall clock time (4 seconds) is waiting for the network response. Run your queries asynchronously and in parallel. If you plan to scrape thousands of sites, look at Doug's answer below. Cloud Functions / Cloud Run is a good vehicle for parallel tasks (stateless/short-term jobs). Using Pub/Sub you can queue up thousands of job messages very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Typically what you do is write a pubsub Cloud Function, and send messages to that function to indicate which smaller amount of work to do.  You can have up to 1000 instances of a function running in parallel on Cloud Functions.  Depending on your goal, you will also need a way to join up the final work when they're all complete.